# How do I properly dispose of a b2Body in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I'm developing a game engine using Starling and Box2D. I'm working hard to make sure it's air-tight in terms of objects being deleted properly i.e. no memory leaks.

Unfortunately I don't have an extremely in-depth understanding of Box2D, so I'm not sure how to ensure bodies are deleted properly.

At the moment I am just using:

```
b2World.DestroyBody(b2Body);
```

And memory seems to be at bay when I profile it over 10-15 minutes. I did notice however that there are some other methods like `b2Body.DestroyFixture(b2Fixture)` which hint that there may be a little more clean up work required.

> What is involved to completely delete a `b2Body`?

And as a small aside; what do I need to do to completely destroy a `b2World`? (When I go back to the menu for example).

Answer (score 0):

I use C++, and there no troubles with it. Deleting the world frees all box2d memory. Methods like DestroyBody, DestroyJoint and DestroyFixture are needed only if you want destroy body, joint or fixture during simulation. Try to check on memory leaks simple box2d app. Sure, trouble is not in box2d.